# How to prevent XSS attacks in ASP.NET Core Razor view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, security, razor, xss

In some part of my `.cshtml` file, I should render `Html` that users entered with `Html-Editor`.

My code is :

```
<div id="description">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Html)
<div>
```

but `@Html.Raw()` is not safe from `XSS Attacks` for example if user's entered Html content was something like this :

```
"<script>alert('XSS attack!')</script>"
```

this script run after entering this page!

how can I prevent from running these scripts(in general XSS attack) while rendering Html ?

Answer (score 2):

You can encode the HTML before rendering it:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.Html))
```

But this is the same as rendering it using:

```
@Model.Html
```

If you render the HTML, use view source, or your browser's inspector, and copy the generated `script` tag, you'll see it's been encoded:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert('XSS attack!')&lt;/script&gt;
```

But I personally prefer using the combination of `Html.Raw` and `Html.Encode` because it makes it clearer to the reader what the intent is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to show **Html Tags** in view, for example I don't want show rendered Html as `<p>Text</p>`! do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: @nimaansari It doesn't work like that. If you want the HTML to rendered, and you don't trust the HTML that you're being given, then you will be vulnerable to XSS as you're _choosing_ not to encode the HTML. Encoding is what prevents XSS, so without it, you are going to vulnerable to it if you don't trust the HTML you are wanting to render.

Comment: @nimaansari Have a read of [this XSS cheat sheet](https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet) and you'll see why it's not just a case of removing `script` tags.